Assistance running PyPSA-ZA
I have tried to follow the instructions to download and run PyPSA-ZA from GitHub. However, after following all the instructions in the README documents, I have failed to get the model to run because snakemake commands are not recognised and I am facing some errors.
Please may I have assistance on running PyPSA-ZA

What instructions did you follow? What errors did you encounter?
